# I created an access database in Access 2007 and split it, now I need to add another table. Is this possible?

Tags: database, ms-access, split

I can add the table in the backend or the front end, but if I add to the front end, it doesn't update on others computers. If I add it to the backend, it didn't show on the front end either. Probably because it is not linked. How would i link the new table AFTER I already split the databse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most circumstances the new table should be created in the back end database so the users can share the table data.  If you have given each user their own copy of the front end database (which you should do), you can create a link in each of them to the new table in the back end.

A better way is to use Tony Toews' [Auto FE Updater](http://autofeupdater.com/).  That way you create the link in only the master copy of the front end database.  Then the next time each user starts the application, her copy of the front end will be replaced with the updated version.  The Auto FE Updater makes it easy to keep the users' copies up to date, and it is free.

**Update**: To link the table in the front end, go to the External Data section of the Ribbon.  Click the Access icon in the Import section of the Ribbon.  On the Get External Data dialog, select the radio button for "Link to the data source by creating a linked table".  Browse to select the back end database.  Then click OK to open the Link Tables dialog, select your new table there, and click OK.

If you want to use code to link the new table, look at Access' help topic for the DoCmd.TransferDatabase Method.

Comment: In my split Accesss databases (typically: Frontend - that's the forms etc. - installed on all of my team's computers. Backend - that's all the tables! - installed on a server in our network) I link (or re-link, if necesssary) the Backend tables using the "Linked Table Manager" in the "External Data" tab. I think this is the usual thing to do...

Answer (score 1):

Go to the front-end, add a link to the new table. Not really a programming question though, consider moving this to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I don't let users link their own tables, I don't care how 'super' they are.

Comment: Uh, the reference to SuperUser is to SuperUser.com, a site that is a better fit for this question that StackOverflow, which is limited to programming questions (which this isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully all of your distributed front end files are all the same; otherwise you'll have to create the link individually (And learn a valuable lesson on why they should all be the same by not allowing users to customize.). You need to add the table to the back end, and create the link in the front end and redistribute.

You may want to look into creating some code in your front end that looks to the back end file, and creates links automatically if they do not exist.

Comment: This is what I thought. How would I link the table created in the backend to the the front end?

Comment: from the front end:  External Data (tab)| Access | Find the file to the back end | choose "Link to the data source by creating a linked table" | Click 'OK' | select table(s) and click 'OK' on Link Tables form.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in a different order. I created the new "test" table locally so I could play with relationships and queries and make sure I have it designed right, then I right clicked and Exported to an Access Database, selecting my back end. Then relinked to the local database using the Import & Linked section of the External Database tab in the ribbon. I had to temporarily rename the local test table so that it could relink, and once it's working the test table can be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

After splitting a database, you usually would put the Frontend part (the forms, queries etc.) onto a number of computers, and the Backend part (the tables) on something like a server, or any computer that is accessible to your co-workers in the network.

So far, you did exactly this, it seems.

As a second step you then have to link the tables (Backend) to the Frontend(s). You usually do this with the so called "Linked Table Manager". It is accessible in the Ribbon, tab "External Data", second button from the left.

[image: Acccess 2010 Linked Table Manager Button]

It opens a dialogue showing what tables are expected.

[image: Access 2010 Linked Table Manager example]

Mark all the tables (there is a button "Select all" to do this), and then hit "OK", or whatever is offered to you. You then should get a file explorer window to select the Backend database. Select that database, confirm, and you should be done.

You have to do this on all computers where your frontend is installed.

When you update the Frontend (e.g. with added functionality, including using additional tables in the Backend) you possibly will have to repeat this procedure on each frontend computer involved.